# Input as an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm playing around with Python3. I want `weight` to be an int but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
age = input("How old are you? ")
height = input("How tall are you? ")
#Since I want to play around, I just want to Turn KG to LBS
#Below is where I'm stuck
weight = int(round(input("How much do you weight? ")*2.2046))

print(f"so you are {age} old, {height} tall and {weight}LBS heavy")
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast your input(which is a `string`) into `int`/`float` first, before you can do number operation (`*`) with it.

i.e.

```
weight = round(int(input("How much do you weight? "))*2.2046)
```

Notice how `int(input('...weight?'))` will be evaluated first, then the `*2.2046` part, finally `round()`.